# Reversing array in v-for only associates some properties with incorrect items (Nuxt 3 / Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a very simple component that lists some articles in order with a `name`, `number`, `link` and `publishedDate`:

```html
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    items: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    },
})
</script>

<template>
    <div class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full gap-6 p-4 lg:p-6">
        <ListItem v-for="item in items" :name="item.name" :link="item.link" :number="item.number" :date="item.publishDate" />
    </div>
</template>
```

This works as expected; all properties are associated with the correct article when rendered and the list is shown oldest to newest (based on how it's returned from the API). I want to show it newest to oldest so I have attempted to reverse it as below:

```
<ListItem v-for="item in items.reverse()" :name="item.name" :link="item.link" :number="item.number" :date="item.publishDate" />
```

This results in the list correctly showing from newest to oldest as expected, with the correct `name`, `number` and `link` shown for each item, but the `date` property does not seem to have reversed so the wrong date is now shown for each item. I'm completely baffled by this as the date should be getting rendered within each iteration of the loop based on the current item, so I can't understand how it can be associating the wrong property with the item.

Am I doing something wrong by reversing the array within the component like this? It feels like a bug but I'm assuming it's user error until proven otherwise.

For clarity, the reason I've done the sort in the component is to allow other sort types, like a shuffle, so I want to be able to do this client-side rather than making a new API call for the re-sort. The `reverse()` is just a simple example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: You're missing `key`, it's necessary with v-for. It's not a good idea to do `reverse` in a template, can be done only once in a computed

Comment: Adding `key` solved the problem with the reverse - seems like it was getting the additional props from the original array without it (I now note that I was using the default in-place patch strategy when not providing `key` which only works when the order doesn't change).

Answer (score 1):

As @estus-flask correctly pointed out in the comments to the question, the solution to this specific problem is to add `:key='id'` to the component in question.

As they also pointed out, and in case anyone finds this, using `.reverse()` on an array in the prop as I was attempting to do is a very bad idea as it causes constant mutation of the prop and causes an infinite recursion loop because the component is modifying its own props. Don't try to do this.